Import doesn't work > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qt_py'
When I try to run my pyqt5 application, the compiler throws this Traceback with couple errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\College\stuff\proj\simulation_proj\app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gui.qt_py.main_window import MainWindow
  File "d:\College\stuff\proj\simulation_proj\gui\qt_py\main_window.py", line 3, in <module>
    from qt_py.simulation_window import SimulationWindow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qt_py'

My project structure is the following:
simulation_proj

app.py

gui:



qt_py:



__init__.py
main_window.py
simulation_window.py




I've been doing this import sentences:
# app.py

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from gui.qt_py.main_window import MainWindow

# main_window.py

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from qt_py.simulation_window import SimulationWindow

# simulation_window.py

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

Question is what's the problem I'm having and what's the best way to manage import statements  in a project structure like mine to run the app.py the way I need.
I tried to run the application app.py but I received ModuleNotFoundError after the compiling process.
I'm expecting my application to run properly and import correctly the modules from the package I need.

Your qt_py file is inside the gui folder.
Your import should either be absolute :
from gui.qt_py.simulation_window import SimulationWindow

Or relative :
from .simulation_window import SimulationWindow

Note the "." before "simulation_window", meaning that the import is relative to the file from which you are importing.

According to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages (unless using a namespace package, a relatively advanced feature). This prevents directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the __all__ variable, described later.

So you simply need to add an empty __init__.py file under gui
